# delete consecutive rows conditionally pandas

Tags: python

I have a df with columns (A, B, C, D, F). I want to:
1) Compare consecutive rows
2) if the absolute difference between consecutive E <=1 AND absolute difference between consecutive C>7, then delete the row with the lowest C value.
Sample Data:

```
     A       B    C      D       E
0   94.5    4.3  26.0   79.0    NaN
1   34.0    8.8  23.0   58.0    54.5
2   54.2    5.4  25.5   9.91    50.2
3   42.2    3.5  26.0   4.91    5.1
4   98.0    8.2  13.0   193.7   5.5
5   20.5    9.6  17.0   157.3   5.3
6   32.9    5.4  24.5   45.9    79.8
```

Desired result:

```
     A       B    C      D       E
0   94.5    4.3  26.0   79.0    NaN
1   34.0    8.8  23.0   58.0    54.5
2   54.2    5.4  25.5   9.91    50.2
3   42.2    3.5  26.0   4.91    5.01
4   32.9    5.4  24.5   45.9    79.8
```

Row 4 was deleted when compared with row 3. Row 5 is now row 4 and it was deleted when compared to row 3.

This code returns the results as boolean (not df with values) and does not satisfy all the conditions.

```
df = (abs(df.E.diff(-1)) <=1 & (abs(df.C.diff(-1)) >7.)
```

The result of the code:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to compare the rows, and a while loop to iterate until no new change happens:

```
while(True):
    rows = len(df)
    df = df[~((abs(df.E - df.E.shift(1)) <= 1)&(abs(df.C - df.C.shift(1)) > 7))]
    df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
    if (rows == len(df)):
        break
```

It produces the desired output:

```
    A       B       C       D       E
0   94.5    4.3     26.0    79.00   NaN
1   34.0    8.8     23.0    58.00   54.5
2   54.2    5.4     25.5    9.91    50.2
3   42.2    3.5     26.0    4.91    5.1
4   32.9    5.4     24.5    45.90   79.8
```